# break one text in several texts

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a challenge. I have this text:

```
Começo
O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados, que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.

Começo
O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados, que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.

Começo
O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados, que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.
```

And i would like to transform into this:

```
var paragraphs = [
 [
  'Começo O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a   apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento  de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados,   que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três  características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.'
 ],

 [
  'Começo O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a   apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento  de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados,   que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três  características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.'
 ],

 [
  'Começo O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a   apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento  de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados,   que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três  características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.'
 ]
]
```

Every paragraph starts and ends with the same words. Is possible to separate? The problem is.. The text somethings has this paragraphs without space to separe them:

```
Começo O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a   apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento  de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados,   que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três  características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.
Começo O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a   apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento  de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados,   que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três  características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.
```

So i was thinking.. How could i do this? And i'm stuck in the following logic:

```
var startsWith = 'Começo';
var endsWith   = 'básico de um texto dissertativo são';

var text = 'Começo O texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a   apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento  de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados,   que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três  características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.'

var reg = new RegExp('(.*'+ startsWith +'\s+)(.*)(\s+'+ endsWith +'.*)');
var match = reg.exec(text);
```

This will push the text between the words.. But i want all the text.

And i'm not receiving exactly how i want.. I would like to receive this array with the para...

Thank you guys.

Comment: Why do you want a single paragraph stored as an array?  I.e., you're trying to get an array of arrays, where each sub-array contains only one element.

Comment: Why not just use lazy matching (considering the paragraphs are not long)? [`Começo[\s\S]*?básicas de um texto dissertativo são`](https://regex101.com/r/tE6lG8/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering paragraphs are not that long, you can use `[\s\S]*?` lazy all symbol matching:

```
Começo[\s\S]*?básicas de um texto dissertativo são
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tE6lG8/1)

Note that lazy matching will match as few characters as necessary to return a valid match (so, the closest rightmost `básicas de um texto dissertativo são` will be the end of each match). To match any single symbol including a newline, it is advisable to use opposite shorthand classes in JavaScript regex, but you can replace `[\s\S]` with a JS-specific `[^]`.

Also, please note that your regex contains `básico` while your text contains `básicas`.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /Começo[\s\S]*?básicas de um texto dissertativo são/g; 
// Or, dynamic building: var re = new RegExp(startsWith +'[\\s\\S]*?'+ endsWith, "g");
var str = 'Começo\nO texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados, que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.\n\nComeço\nO texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados, que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.\n\nComeço\nO texto dissertativo argumentativo tem como principais características a apresentação de um raciocínio, a defesa de um ponto de vista ou o questionamento de uma determinada realidade. O autor se vale de argumentos, de fatos, de dados, que servirão para ajudar a justificar as ideias que ele irá desenvolver. As três características básicas de um texto dissertativo são.';
var m;
var arr = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    arr.push(m[0]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @stribizhev.. that's exactly what i want !!